# grouped_option_select with helper results in n+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a grouped_option_select along with a helper function to have the label for each line of the select provide included data. This is resulting in N+1 queries and I'm not sure of how to resolve this 'the rails way'.

Thanks in advance.

The model:

```
class FbrlCode < ActiveRecord::Base
    nilify_blanks

    has_many :positions
    has_many :people, through: :positions

    belongs_to :brl_family

    has_one :labor_category, :through => :brl_family
    has_one :company, :through => :labor_category

    validates :fbrl_code, :brl_family, presence: true
    validates :fbrl_code, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
    validates_associated :brl_family

    def fbrl_code_with_info
        "#{fbrl_code} : #{brl_family.brl_family} : #{labor_category.labor_category}"
    end
end
```

Here is the relevant grouped_collection_select:

```
  <%= f.label :fbrl_code %>
  <%= grouped_collection_select( :position, :fbrl_code_id, @companies, :fbrl_codes, :company_name, :id, :fbrl_code_with_info , { :prompt => 'Select FBRL Code', :multiple => false } ) %><br>
```

And the eager loading in the controller

```
  @companies = Company.includes(:labor_categories).includes(:brl_families).includes(:fbrl_codes).includes(:positions).distinct
```

Output from the rails server:

```
Started GET "/positions/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-08 14:59:28 -0400
Processing by PositionsController#new as HTML
  Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "companies".* FROM "companies"
  LaborCategory Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" WHERE "labor_categories"."company_id" IN (4, 2, 6, 7, 3, 1, 5)
  BrlFamily Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "brl_families".* FROM "brl_families" WHERE "brl_families"."labor_category_id" IN (9, 10, 11, 5, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 14, 15, 16, 17, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 12, 13)
  FbrlCode Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "fbrl_codes".* FROM "fbrl_codes" WHERE "fbrl_codes"."brl_family_id" IN (9, 10, 11, 1, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 14, 15, 16, 17, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 12, 13)
  Position Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."fbrl_code_id" IN (22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 13, 14, 15, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 34, 35, 36, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 30, 31, 32, 33)
  LaborCategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  LaborCategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  LaborCategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  LaborCategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  LaborCategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 66]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 66]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 66]]
  LaborCategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 67]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 67]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 67]]
  LaborCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 68]]
...
  LaborCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  LaborCategory Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "labor_categories".* FROM "labor_categories" INNER JOIN "brl_families" ON "labor_categories"."id" = "brl_families"."labor_category_id" WHERE "brl_families"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  HireType Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "hire_types".* FROM "hire_types"
  ExperienceCategory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "experience_categories".* FROM "experience_categories"
  Experience Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "experiences".* FROM "experiences" WHERE "experiences"."experience_category_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
  Rendered positions/_positions_experience_fields.html.erb (20.9ms)
  Rendered positions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (489.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (62.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidenav.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 564ms (Views: 514.4ms | ActiveRecord: 40.9ms)
```

It is a very large set of queries, so I truncated it.

Comment: when preloading the association, there should not be an n+1 query! what exactly are the resulting queries?

Comment: Every access to the helper function `fbrl_code_with_info` is resulting in a new query for the `brl_family` and the `labor_category`. I expect that this is because the helper is in the model, but that is where I understand is the correct place for it.

Comment: I tried replacing `:fbrl_codes` in the `grouped_collection_request` with an object `@fbrl_codes` with the appropriate includes, but that didn't change the result.

Comment: load your rails console, load the `@companies` with the eager-loading like in your controller and call the helper method on the first item, post the sql logs here.

Comment: I don't know how to do that with the console so I added a truncated server output.

Comment: I was able to run the @companies with eager loading, but I do not know the syntax for calling the helper function in the model.

Comment: my best guess is that the distinct is the issue here. try to remove it and see if the n+1 goes away. you will need to make the resultset uniq in the ruby code then.

Comment: It is not the distinct qualifier. I have tried removing it with no effect. Plus you can see the eager loaded SQL statements after the companies are loaded.  Somehow the problem is that the helper method is in the model, so it is calling the queries for each of the records as it creates the selection.

Comment: first of "helper method" does not describe it properly. it's just a method on the model. it does not matter where you put it. either the model has all it's associations loaded, or it does not.